# Simulate pouring flour (powder) in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I need to pour flour (powder) from one box to another by tilting the iOS device, can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: This question is a bit too vague. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look over the particle systems. It should be exactly what you need. 
If you open up the cocos2d project, check the targets and switch to the ParticleTest target, build and run.

Answer (score 0):

If it's going to be dynamic (i.e. not just an pre-rendered animation), you'd need some physics calculation. Check out box2d and chipmunk for more support (you'd probably have to write your own particle systems for them).